# Can a cracked quartz shower wall be repaired to safely support a sliding door install?

Tags: shower, cracks, quartz

During our bathroom remodel the shower door top rail was being installed and the glass installer cracked the quartz slab wall. We think they tightened the hardware down too tight/unevenly and crushed the stone.

Contractor says they have a "granite guy" who can repair the cracks. My concern is the integrity of repair after reinstalling due to the weight of the rail and hanging glass shower doors. **Any advice on whether a repair can be sufficient??** Of course they are telling me it will be fine. They don't want to eat the cost of a whole new slab. I am very skeptical. Otherwise they rip the entire thing out and redo... which is going to be so invasive and time consuming.[image: pic of cracked quartz]

Comment: I might suggest getting a couple of estimates from _other_ stone/tub installers to see what they'd suggest doing. Bring them out and ask how they'd repair it and what it would cost. Make no mention of the current contractor (they may know him and intentionally support him and/or throw him under the bus, depending on their relationship).

Comment: This is why you want a contractor with insurance. Then the insurance gets to pay for the new slab as opposed to you getting a half-fast repair to save the contractor some coin for properly fixing the damage they are responsible for causing.

Comment: This may be just exposing my inexperience with quartz slabs like this, but I feel as though drilling 4 mounting holes that close to the edge of the slab and then stuffing plastic anchors in them to screw into is just begging for this exact situation to occur. If I were DIYing this I would have made sure to have a solid stud behind there and then drilled slightly oversize holes through the slab so as to fix the rail to the stud rather than to the slab.